# Can I use a multisample buffer for things other than anti-aliasing?

Tags: opengl, directx, shader, transparency, multisampling

I did a bit of searching, but the only results I found regarded anti-aliasing and the mechanics behind it.

I want to use a multi-sample buffer for things other than anti-aliasing.  Specifically, what I have in mind is a form of order-independent transparency, storing a different color and depth value in each sample (ideally the N fragments closest to the camera).

Is this even possible in the first place?  Has it been done before, and if so how?  Even if it were possible, is it any more memory-efficient than just allocating another N framebuffers?

If something like this would require a compute shader or OpenCL, that's fine, I'm just curious to see if it's possible in the first place.

This question isn't specific to OpenGL or DirectX, since the hardware would be the same in either case.

PS. Please don't just point me towards other methods of order-independent transparency, this question is specifically about whether the multisample buffer can be used for atypical means.

Comment: I don't think so unless you can program the rasterizer. It might be possible with DX12 but I have no idea. That might make it available for non-anti-aliasing use. But your idea still seems impossible.

Comment: Never tried it myself, but starting from OpenGL 4.0, one can set the sample mask from the fragment shader using the `gl_SampleMask` variable [(reference)](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL)#Fragment_shader_outputs).

Comment: Interesting idea, but i don't see this working in any way. Even with `gl_SampleMask` from @BDL the edges of the triangles can't be handled correctly, because you can't write to pixels that are not covered by the primitive. For example when using 2x2 multisampling and your primitive covers 3 of the 4 sub-pixels, the 4th sub pixel cannot be written.

Comment: I would start by having an additional texture for per-pixel counting. Then one could in the fragment shader set the sample mask such that each write operation is distributed to another sample. Basically this uses the multisampletexture's samples just to store different values per pixel. In my oppinion, it would be easier nowadays to make use of the Image Load/Store features, which make it ways easier to write such things.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is that the system is hard-coded to use multisampling for, well, *multisampling*, not for the storage of arbitrary data.

Through the use of the [`gl_SampleMask` output](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Other_outputs), you can direct the results of a fragment shader to a specific sample of the multisample buffer. You could then use a shader to perform a custom multisample resolve in order to do your transparency sorting or whatever it is you plan to do here.

In theory, of course. In practice however, `gl_SampleMask` will be logically and-ed with the sample mask computed by the rasterizer for that fragment. So if you set the `gl_SampleMask` to write to a particular sample that isn't covered by your fragment, nothing gets written.

There's nothing you can do about this. Even explicitly activating per-sample fragment shader evaluation will not help you, since the system will still compute and use that mask, based on the geometry you render with.

So generally speaking, no, there's not much you can use multisampling for besides antialiasing.